# Implement density function

Tags: algorithm, function, distribution, montecarlo

I am going through my book , it states that " Write a sampling algorithm for this density function"

```
y=x^2+(2/3)*x+1/3; 0 <  < 1
```

Or I can use Monte Carlo?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you want to generate random `x` values that have the distribution specified by density `y(x)`.

It's often desirable to derive the cumulative distribution function by integrating the density, and use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate `x` values.  In your case the the CDF is a third order polynomial which doesn't factor to yield a simple cube-root solution, so you would have to use a numerical solver to find the inverse.  Time to consider alternatives.

Another option is to use the [acceptance/rejection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling). After checking the derivative, it's clear that your density is convex, so it's easy to create a bounding function `b(x)` by drawing a straight line from `f(0)` to `f(1)`.  This yields `b(x) = 1/3 + 5x/3`.  This bounding function has area 7/6, while your `f(x)` has an area of 1, since it is a valid density.  Consequently, 6/7 of points generated uniformly under `b(x)` will also fall under `f(x)`, and only 1 out of 7 attempts will fail in the rejection scheme.  Here's a plot of `f(x)` and `b(x)`:

[image: Plot of f(x) and b(x) showing relatively tight bounding]

Since `b(x)` is linear, it is easy to generate `x` values using it as a distribution after scaling by 6/7 to make it a valid distribution function.  The algorithm, expressed in pseudocode, then becomes:

```
function generate():
  while TRUE:
    x <- (sqrt(1 + 35 * U(0,1)) - 1) / 5     # inverse CDF transform of b(x)
    if U(0, b(x)) <= f(x):
      return x
  end while
end function
```

where `U(a,b)` means generate a value uniformly distributed between `a` and `b`, `f(x)` is your density, and `b(x)` is the bounding function described above.

I implemented the algorithm described above to generate 100,000 candidate values, of which 14,199 (~1/7) were rejected, as expected. The end results are presented in the following histogram, which you can compare to `f(x)` in the plot above.

[image: Histogram of generated data having density f(x)]

Comment: If I want to use  rejection method how to that in algorithm way? Thanks in advance

Comment: A program is just a concrete implementation of an algorithm, so I'm not sure what you're saying.  I expressed it as an algorithm, even though I then implemented it to show you the histogram.

Comment: If you look at the pseudocode I provided, it generates candidates but only accepts them conditionally.

Comment: So if you think what I wrote is a program, not an algorithm, what language do you think it's in?  (Hint: there is no such language.)

Comment: No it just I get confused :( for this line   x <- (sqrt(1 + 35 * U(0,1)) - 1) / 5?

Comment: `<-` is common pseudocode notation for "evaluate the thing on the right and assign it to the variable on the left."  In other words, assign `x` the value you get by evaluating the algebra on the right.

Comment: `sqrt` is common notation for "square root".

Comment: I mean how you got 35?

Comment: That entire line is the result of using the inverse transform calculation on scaled b(x), as stated in the comment in the pseudocode.  That's how the math works out for *your* density function.  You asked for the algorithm, not the calculus-based derivation, so I gave you the former and sketched the steps and provided links for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have a function y(x), which takes a value between [0,1] and returns the value of y. You just need to provide a random value of x and return the corresponding value of y.

```
def getSample():
  #get uniform random number
  x = numpy.random.random()

  #sample my custom function
  return y(x)
```